# Angular 7 return one json object from web api and access on page

Tags: angular

I can successfully query an API and return a JSON list and then iterate through the list within my HTML page.

I have another part of my API that returns one result and I am struggling getting the data to show on the page.

If I have the following method:

```
getonofflinegt1():Observable<any>{
        return this.httpclient.get("https://localhost:44359/api/tagdetail/mytag");
    }
```

Which returns the following (it will always be 1):

```
{"tagname":"mytag", "value":"99"}
```

what data type do I pass it too and then how do I access it on the screen?

For the list I assign it to the following:

```
lstonoffline:mytags[];
```

and then iterate through the list using `ngFor`

Comment: 1. Define an interface for the object you receive. 2. Replace `<any>`by `<TheInterfaceYouDefined>`. 3. Assign what you receive to a field of type `TheInterfaceYouDefined`, since... that's what you receive. Display it in your template directly, without using ngFor, since there no loop to do.

Comment: @JBNizet by interface do mean the class I have for tag detail

Comment: If you already have an interface defined for that, then use it, of course. Why use `any`? I wouldn't use a class though, but an interface: JSON.parse() (which is used by the http client) will never actually create an instance of your class, that it doesn't know about.

Answer (score -1):

I assume `mytags` is a model you already have, so might look something like this?

```
export class mytags {

    constructor(
        public tagname: string,
        public value: string
    )
}
```

You could add a static method to your model class to allow a single instance of `mytags` to be created from the API response:

```
export class mytags {

    constructor(
        public tagname: string,
        public value: string
    )

    public static createFromResponse(response: any): mytags {
        return new mytags(
            response.tagname,
            response.value
        );
    }
}
```

And then map the response to the model:

```
getonofflinegt1():Observable<mytags>{
    return this.httpclient.get("https://localhost:44359/api/tagdetail/mytag").pipe(
                map(response => { return mytags.createFromResponse(response); 
            });
        );
}
```